# How to pivot across two columns using MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I've got a content value table and content type table that need to be dynamically combined into one aggregated view. Here's some pseudo data to demo their schema and relationship:

Value Table:

```
ID      TYPEID      TEXT      MARKUP
1.           1.      "Some text"    "Some markup"
....
```

Type Table:

```
ID       TYPENAME
1.       "Some type"
...
```

Desired Output:

```
ValueID          Sometype           SometypeMarkup        AnotherType        AnotherTypeMarkup   ...
1.                   "sometype text"           "sometype markup"      "anothertype text"       "anothertype markup"
2.          ....
...
```

Currently I am using a procedure to dynamically select the type names and their values using two pivot tables like below:

`Select p.valueid , @colunns from valuetable (pivot max(text) from (typenames in (@typecolums)) p) pt join (select * from valuetable pivot max(markup) from (typenames in (@typecolumns) pp) pm on pt.valueid = pm.valueid group by pt.valueid`

Is there a tidier way to archive the desired output like pivoting across two columns?

Comment: This seems to be a scenario of self join. Nothing related to pivot.

Comment: How many rows per ID do you expect? And please state your RDBMS (vendor and version)

Comment: It might help if you provide a little more sample data that actually demonstrates what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi, if my answer helped you to solve your question it would be very kind of you to vote it up and/or mark it as accepted. If not, please give some comment what else you would need...

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you can use PIVOT but not with more than one column

There is one trick: Concatenate your data and let it look like XML. This compound data is pivotable and - as it is XML - you can divide it typesafe and easily:

```
DECLARE @tblType TABLE(ID INT,Caption VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tblType VALUES
 (1,'Type1')
,(2,'Type2')
,(3,'Type3');

DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT,TYPEID INT,[TEXT] VARCHAR(100),MARKUP VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,1,'type 11','markup 11')
,(1,2,'type 21','markup 21')
,(1,3,'type 31','markup 31')
,(2,2,'type 22','markup 22')
,(2,3,'type 32','markup 32')
,(3,1,'type 13','markup 13')
,(3,3,'type 33','markup 33');

SELECT p.ID
      ,Casted.Type1Xml.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)') AS Type1_Text 
      ,Casted.Type1Xml.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)') AS Type1_Markup 
      ,Casted.Type2Xml.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)') AS Type2_Text 
      ,Casted.Type2Xml.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)') AS Type2_Markup 
      ,Casted.Type3Xml.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)') AS Type3_Text 
      ,Casted.Type3Xml.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)') AS Type3_Markup 
FROM(
    SELECT tbl.ID 
          ,tp.Caption
          ,'<x>' + tbl.[TEXT] + '</x><x>' + tbl.MARKUP + '</x>' AS ConcatenatedData
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
    INNER JOIN @tblType AS tp ON tbl.TYPEID=tp.ID
) AS x
PIVOT
(
    MIN(ConcatenatedData) FOR Caption IN(Type1,Type2,Type3)
) AS p
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT CAST(p.Type1 AS XML) AS Type1Xml
          ,CAST(p.Type2 AS XML) AS Type2Xml 
          ,CAST(p.Type3 AS XML) AS Type3Xml 
) AS Casted
```

The result

```
1   type 11 markup 11   type 21 markup 21   type 31 markup 31
2   NULL    NULL        type 22 markup 22   type 32 markup 32
3   type 13 markup 13   NULL    NULL        type 33 markup 33
```